# What is wrong with this simple sqlite select statement code in python to produce this binding error?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I have this simple SQLite code in python.

```
box = 'XDS.SI'
sqlite_cur.execute('''
                   SELECT id from box_infos WHERE box = ?;
                   ''', box
                   )
```

I get the following error;

```
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 3 supplied.
```

When I run the simple select statement in another way,

```
sqlite_cur.execute('''
                   SELECT id from box_infos WHERE box = 'XDS.SI';
                   '''
                   )
```

I received no error. What is wrong with the first code segment? Both looks similar.

I am using sqlite3 and python v3.6

Comment: You need a comma after `box` to make it a tuple. A string is a sequence and it's being unpacked character-by-character

Comment: @roganosh, thanks for the tip. I've got the answer. One minor detail to add. Besides adding the comma, one needs to put in brackets around `box,`. One thing I don't understand. Why is it necessary to make it a tuple?

Comment: Yep sorry, you need the brackets too. Because the cursor _expects_ a sequence of parameters to be supplied and naturally unpacks whatever argument it is given. In the case of a single parameter that happens to be a string, it will then start unpacking that string and find that there aren't enough `?` to accommodate each character. Once you supply a single-item tuple, it will find the full string at the first index and then there is nothing else for it to unpack. In that case, it's iterating the container, not the string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question, thanks to the comment from roganjosh. Purpose of `(box,)` is to make it a tuple.

Thanks again to roganjosh, the reason for making it a tuple is because the cursor expects a sequence of parameters to be supplied and naturally unpacks whatever argument it is given. In the case of a single parameter that happens to be a string, it will then start unpacking that string and find that there aren't enough ? to accommodate each character. Once you supply a single-item tuple, it will find the full string at the first index and then there is nothing else for it to unpack. In that case, it's iterating the container, not the string

```
box = 'XDS.SI'
sqlite_cur.execute('''
                   SELECT id from box_infos WHERE box = ?;
                   ''', (box,)
                   )
```